# Runge kutta 4 Matlab program isn't working

Tags: octave, runge-kutta

I need to solve a system of first-order differential equations using Runge Kutta 4 orders (the scheme I've used may not be the most common but it's the one I need to use).

The code doesn't work and I don't know why.
I'm using Octave and I have a problem with the command window, so I can't see the error.

I tried with the debug and everything went well for the calculation of k1,k2,k3,k4 but when I got to the calculation of v(i+1, :) the program seemed to crash.

Here's my code, the first part is my file where I define the parameters, my function and where I call my ode4' function. The code for my ode4 function is the second code.

```
clear all
clc



function dtdy=kernel(t,y,sigma,beta,rho)
  dtdy=zeros(2,1)
  dtdy(1)=sigma*y(2)
  dtdy(2)=rho*y(2)+beta*y(1)
end

sigma=1;
rho=-0.9;
beta=-25;
h=0.08;
t=0:h:10;
y0=[0 0.01];

Rk4=ode4(@(t,y)kernel(t,y,sigma,beta,rho),t,y0);
```

```
function[tout,v]=ode4(odefun,tspan,v0)
v=zeros(length(tspan),length(v0));
v(1,:)=v0 %initial condition for y(0)
h=tspan(2)-tspan(1); % extract h value from tspan
tout=tspan;

for i=1:(length(tspan)-1)
 
  k1=odefun(tspan(i),v(i,:));
  k2=odefun(tspan(i)+(h/2),v(i,:)+(h/2).*k1);
  k3=odefun(tspan(i)+(h/2),v(i,:)+(h/2).*k2);
  k4=odefun(tspan(i)+h,v(i,:)+h.*k3);
  v(i+1,:)=v(i,:)+(h/6)*(k1+(2*k2)+(2*k3)+k4);
end
end
```

If somebody could help me to find the mistake in my code it could be great.

Comment: “I have a problem with the command window, so I can't see the error.” The first thing you need to do is fix your environment so that you can see the error messages. You cannot do any form of programming if you can’t see the error messages. We can’t help you either if we don’t know what the problem is.

Comment: Assuming you're running windows 11 and are using (perhaps unknowingly) the new Windows Terminal, its a known issue. Please see workaround at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614821/octaves-comand-window-glitches-when-i-run-a-script

Comment: Thank you very much, Nick j I now have a working command window, which I hadn't had from the start, and I've been able to solve my problem.

Comment: From the tag descriptions of both the `octave` and `matlab` tags: _"Don’t use both the [matlab] and [octave] tags, unless the question is explicitly about the similarities or differences between the two."_. Please read the tag descriptions before using them in future questions